# Chrome renders <title> element as <h1> when using webGL

Tags: html, google-chrome, webgl

I'm finding that Chrome (running v 23) both on Winxp and Ubuntu is rendering the content of my "title" tag in the body as a "h1" tag, but only in this page where I'm using webGL:

http://www.fernandaramos.com/glsl

When inspecting the code it appears as well, but when viewing the source code you can see there is no h1 tag in the body.

Is this a Chrome bug or am I missing something?

Regards.

Comment: Weird. But if the change takes place after the page renders, what is the biggest problem this could cause?

Comment: webgl-utils.js changed to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

h1 element is created by webgl-utils.js

Comment: Right, thought I had checked that. What is that for? In firefox it doesn't happen, athough window.top is supported as well. Thanks Loris